Multiple desktop files using the same system wide /usr/share/application desltop files
I have an application in which I have created a /usr/share/application/foo.desktop from my dpkg.
I wish to have multiple instances of LINK types on my ~/Desktop/ which vary only the Name and Exec. It had looked easy and my attempt at it 'sort of' worked, except the Desktop/foo1.desktop and foo2.desktop do not get the Icon from the /usr/share/application file.
What I want seems simple enough. You have a standard desktop file installed by package and then link to it, and each link varies some key parameters.
In my case this is a type of recorder, and I would initiate multiple different data stream records.
ChatGPT seems to think this cannot be done. I am skeptical as most of it does seem to work. I feel that I am missing some key point so suggestions are welcome. If anyone is interested, I can post examples.

You cannot. Linking (man ln) alters inodes (directory entries), and does not fiddle with file contents.
If you want different behavior, you'll have to have different files.
At installation time, you could do something like:
sed -e `/^Exec=/s%=.*%=/path/to/yours%`
 foo.desktop >foo1.desktop

You can have multiple -es to change different lines.
Read man sed and info sed.

Thanks. I was pretty sure I was stuffed on that approach, but I find it is always good to see if someone else knows something I don't.

@DaleAmon Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.
